# R Programming arithmetic equation logic

Tags: r

The working behind the solution or arithmetic equation like 2+3-4*6/3-2^3/4+7-6*2**3/2+2-4+5 in R programming ? The logic behind the solving of the equation.

Comment: You're looking for a way to solve an equation? Have you tried anything yet? Can you get a simple example to work?

Comment: this is a question asked . The RStudio is showing the answer -19. But i dont know the logic behind it.

Comment: Do some searching. Google with `algorithm arithmetic expression` and start reading the first few results.

Comment: if you're asking how to solve this equation in R, just type it in the console and you will get your answer...If you're asking why -19 is the answer, think operator precedence: `2+3+((-4*6)/3)+((-2^3)/4)+7+((-6*(2**3))/2)+2-4+5`. Multiply and divide has the same precedence, so it gets evaluated from left to right. Exponentiation has precedence over multiply so `2**3` get evaluated first.

Comment: please share operator precedence

Comment: This is basic [order of operations](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/orderops.htm), which translates to what I just commented about in R.

Answer (score 0):

In order to know how R evaluates an arithmetic expression like the one in your question, you need to understand the operator precedence in R. Operator precedence, also known as the *order of operations*, is explained   on R's `Syntax` help page. Type `?Syntax` at any R prompt and you'll see:

```
 The following unary and binary operators are defined.  They are
 listed in precedence groups, from highest to lowest.

   ‘:: :::’           access variables in a namespace              
   ‘$ @’              component / slot extraction                  
   ‘[ [[’             indexing                                     
   ‘^’                exponentiation (right to left)               
   ‘- +’              unary minus and plus                         
   ‘:’                sequence operator                            
   ‘%any%’            special operators (including ‘%%’ and ‘%/%’) 
   ‘* /’              multiply, divide                             
   ‘+ -’              (binary) add, subtract                       
   ‘< > <= >= == !=’  ordering and comparison                      
   ‘!’                negation                                     
   ‘&  &&’            and                                          
   ‘| ||’             or                                           
   ‘~’                as in formulae                               
   ‘-> ->>’           rightwards assignment                        
   ‘<- <<-’           assignment (right to left)                   
   ‘=’                assignment (right to left)                   
   ‘?’                help (unary and binary)
```

This tells you that `^` is evaluated before `*` and `\`, which in turn are evaluated before `+` and `-`, and so on.